# To replace the first character of the last line of a unix file with the file name

Tags: unix, replace, filenames

We need a shell script that retrieves all txt files in the current directory and for each file checks if it is an empty file or contains any data in it (which I believe can be done with wc command).

If it is empty then ignore it else since in our condition, all txt files in this directory will either be empty or contain huge data wherein the last line of the file will be like this:

```
Z|11|21||||||||||
```

That is the last line has the character `Z` then `|` then `an integer` then `|` then `an integer` then certain numbers of `|` symbols.

If the file is not empty, then we just assume it to have this format. Data before the last line are garbled and not necessary for us but there will be at least one line before the last line, i.e. there will be at least two lines guaranteed if the file is non-empty.

We need a code wherein, if the file is non-empty, then it takes the file, replaces the 'Z' in the last line with 'filename.txt' and writes the new data into another file say tempfile. The last line will thus become as:

```
filename.txt|11|21|||||||
```

Remaining part of the line remains same. From the tempfile, the last line, i.e., `filename.txt|int|int|||||` is taken out and merged into a finalfile. The contents of tempfile is cleared to receive data from next filename.txt in the same directory. finalfile has the edited version of the last lines of all non-empty txt files in that directory.

Eg: file1.txt has data as

```
....
....
....
Z|1|1|||||
```

and file2.txt has data as

```
....
....
....
Z|2|34|||||
```

After running the script, new data of file1.txt becomes

```
.....
.....
.....
file1.txt|1|1||||||
```

This will be written into a new file say temp.txt which is initially empty. From there the last line is merged into a file final.txt. So, the data in final.txt is:

```
file1.txt|1|1||||||
```

After this merging, the data in temp.txt is cleared
New data of file2.txt becomes

```
...
...
...
file2.txt|2|34||||||
```

This will be written into the same file temp.txt. From there the last line is merged into the same file final.txt.
So, the data in final.txt is

```
file1.txt|1|1||||||
file2.txt|2|34||||||
```

After considering N number of files that was returned to be as of type txt and non-empty and within the same directory, the data in final.txt becomes

```
file1.txt|1|1||||||
file2.txt|2|34||||||
file3.txt|8|3||||||
.......
.......
.......
fileN.txt|22|3|||||
```

For some of the conditions, I already know the command, like
For finding files in a directory of type text,

```
find <directory> -type f -name "*.txt"
```

For taking the last line and merging it into another file

```
tail -1 file.txt>>destination.txt
```

Comment: It does sound like someone's asking SO to do their job for them.  If so, how much will you pay for a solution :)  In case it's not, some basic bash code below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'sed' to replace the "z" character.  You'll be in a loop, so you can use the filename that you have in that.  This just removes the Z, and then echos the line and filename.

Good luck.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=test.txt
line=`tail -1 $filename | sed "s/Z/$filename/"`
echo $line
```

**Edit:**

Did you run your `find` command first, and see the output?  It has of course a `./` at the start of each line.  That will break sed, since sed uses `/` as a delimiter.  It also will not work with your problem statement, which does not have an extra "/" before the filename.  You said current directory, and the command you give will traverse **ALL** subdirectories.  Try being simple and using `LS`.

```
# `2>/dev/null` puts stderr to null, instead of writing to screen.  this stops
# us getting the "no files found" (error) and thinking it's a file!
for filename in `ls *.txt 2>/dev/null` ; do
    ... stuff ...
done
```

Comment: for filename in `find . -type f -name "*.txt"`
do
line=`tail -1 $filename|sed "s/Z/$filename/"`
echo $line
done

Comment: Without a loop, the above command works perfectly.
Within a loop, it doesn't work.

for filename in `find . -type f -name "*.txt"` 
do 
line=`tail -1 $filename|sed "s/Z/$filename/"` 
echo $line 
done

The output was:
sed: Function s/Z/./bk1.txt/ cannot be parsed.

sed: Function s/Z/./bk2.txt/ cannot be parsed.

sed: Function s/Z/./bk3.txt/ cannot be parsed.

Find command returns filename as ./bk1.txt, ./bk2.txt, etc. Using the variable filename anywhere accesses the contents of the file, but can't be used to input the filename itself

Comment: sounds like your file names contain a the currrent directory "./"

Comment: also, if you don't care about the occasional error, you can just write `for filename in *.txt ; do`.   ";" just lets you put the do on the same line.